# How to read a binary file?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to send a file between a client and a server in my home network. I just want to test with a simple file, `client.txt`.

The client program should read X bytes and send it over the tcp socket I've created, but I cant wrap my head around how to do the sending part:

```
f = open("client.txt", "rb")
while 1:
// should read X bytes and send to the socket
```

I think I need to check if the data I want to send is valid, if a file for instance is smaller then the amount (1024 for instance) I'm sending in each batch.... or does it not work that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned you have problems setting up the server part, I'll rip this out from Python documentation and edit it slightly:

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 50007

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

f = open("client.txt", "rb")
while 1:
    data = f.read(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

The relevant document can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example)

Comment: excelent! but do i need to check if f.read(1024) is out of bounds? it the file is 1524 bytes big, that would result in 2 reads, but in the second time around there is only 500b left?

Comment: No, as unholysampler mentioned, read(num) will return _at most_ num bytes from the file (after reaching end of file it'll return an empty string), so the cycle will break after reaching EOF; since Python regards empty strings as 'False' and `if not data` will therefore evaluate to True.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` takes an optional parameter that specifies the number of bytes to read in.

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

> To read a file’s contents, call
>   f.read(size), which reads some
>   quantity of data and returns it as a
>   string. size is an optional numeric
>   argument. When size is omitted or
>   negative, the entire contents of the
>   file will be read and returned; it’s
>   your problem if the file is twice as
>   large as your machine’s memory.
>   Otherwise, at most size bytes are read
>   and returned. If the end of the file
>   has been reached, f.read() will return
>   an empty string ("").